# JAVA - How to change states between single keyPressed of character 'F' / 'f'?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, actionlistener, keypress

At the moment , when I hit `F` or `f` :

```
    private static final char FILL_POLYGON_LOWERCASE = 'f';
    private static final char FILL_POLYGON = 'F';

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent) 
{
    PolygonFiller polyFiller = new PolygonFiller();
    char key = keyEvent.getKeyChar();

    switch(key)
    {
        /**
         *  Fill the polygons 
         */
        case FILL_POLYGON:      
        {
            if (greenLightForFilling == true)
            {
                fillPolygon(polyFiller);

                System.out.print("called");
            }

            break;
        }  // end FILL_POLYGON


        case FILL_POLYGON_LOWERCASE:
        {
            if (greenLightForFilling == true)
            {
                fillPolygon(polyFiller);
            }
            break;  
        }
...

}
```

The program goes into `fillPolygon(polyFiller);` .

Meaning , when I hit for the first time `f` , I go into `fillPolygon()` .

How can I go into some other method , for example `other()` , when I hit `f` or `F` **again** ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So the thing is, if you click f/F you goto fill polygon, and pressing f/F again will call other().

This can be a classic case of Stateful Class.

Have an attribute in this at class level.

And on entering f/F check the value and increment it by one.
And on entering f/F again, check the value and increment it by one.

Before each increment you should check whether,

```
//Am assuming that there are more than two functions, else could use boolean

if (value == 1) {
    fillpolygon();
}

else if (value == 2) {
    other();
}
else if (value == 2) {
    some_other();
}
```

Remember the entry point will be a single function, from there the flow is delegated based on checks similar to this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ Boolean doesn't help me ,because if I move the mouse ,then the polygons that I filled - disappear .

Comment: You should check your code, why it gets empty. Just by using boolean, nothing should happen. If the variable is handled properly. And all the functions which are being called previously are being called now too.

Comment: Okay ,something makes the filling of the polygons to disappear ,  only when the mouse moves . Would you like me to post the code ?

Comment: If it solves your problem, you can post the same for reference for others.

Answer (score 0):

Store the previously used button in a variable like 'currentCommand' and 'previousCommand'. Everytime you detect a new input you put current to previous and store the new one in the current member.
Or maybe if you want more than the last two key pressed use a stack.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I go into some other method, for example `other()`, when I hit `f` or `F` again ?

You need to introduce a boolean flag.

This is a very simple example of a [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).